# Troubleshooting Unity & Unity Hub Problems Behind Firewall

Tags: unity

I'm teaching game design at a high school in the US. This means that we're behind a firewall that does packet inspection. Our lab machines are running Windows 10 and have the school's certificate installed as a "Trusted Root Certification Authority" (as seen in `certlm`).

The problem I'm seeing are:

- Unity Hub (2.0.0) silently fails when trying to download Unity installs
- Unity (2019.1.3f1) complains about a "self-signed certificate in the trust chain" (roughly)

[This post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/allow-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain.579046/) from the Unity Forums suggests that Unity might know how to read the local computer's list of trusted certificates, but there are also responses indicating that it may not always work.

My questions:

- Where do Unity and Unity Hub log certificate errors (do they)?
- Suggestions for troubleshooting?